# analytic function in a domain.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be a domain and $U$ contains both $z$ and its conjugate for each $z$. Show that $U \cap \mathbb{R} \neq \emptyset$. Let $f$ be an analytic on $U$. Suppose that $f(x)$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in U \cap \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$.

I already show first part $ U \cap \mathbb{R}$ is nonempty. 
but for the rest part of the question I am not sure about how to proceed? it look obvious when $z=x$ then $f^\prime=0$ and $f$ is constant so we can get the equality we want. but when $z$ is in U but not in $\mathbb{R}$. I need you help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function

$$g\colon U \to \mathbb{C};\quad g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}.$$

Show that $g$ is holomorphic. Use $U\cap \mathbb{R}\neq\varnothing$ and $f(U\cap\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ to conclude $g = f$.

Comment: can you please explain it more ???if g is holomorphic in U why would this give g=f?

Comment: Look at $U\cap\mathbb{R}$, what can you say about $f$ and $g$ there?

Comment: they are equal on  U∩R. it means they are equal everywhere on U since???

Comment: What theorem do you know that says two holomorphic functions are identical when some condition is fulfilled?